# How to Determine the Average CPU Percentage using a Powershell Command and Output the CPU Percentage as a Numeric Percentage with no Labels

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu

I'm am working to get a powershell command that allows me to pull the average cpu percentage over all the cores for a remote server, and output the value as just the numeric percentage. I am Close but have not been able find a way to just get the Numeric value. The Following is the command I am using followed by the output.

```
Get-WmiObject -computer server -class win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | FL average


Average : 30.5
```

Thanks in advance for any Help!

Comment: average over what period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Select-Object`'s `ExpandProperty` parameter to get the value of a property. Updated script:

```
Get-WmiObject -computer server -class win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```