# Problems getting CPU Average in PowerShell from a server with two CPU's

Tags: windows, powershell, cpu-usage

I am trying to run the following on a remote machine with two physical CPU's and so it doesn't return any value.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -computername X | 
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
```

*(Source: [How to Determine the Average CPU Percentage using a Powershell Command and Output the CPU Percentage as a Numeric Percentage with no Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706117/how-to-determine-the-average-cpu-percentage-using-a-powershell-command-and-outpu))*

This is the output when I run `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -computername X`:

```
Caption           : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 4
DeviceID          : CPU0
Manufacturer      : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed     : 2195
Name              : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4850 v3 @ 2.20GHz
SocketDesignation : None

Caption           : Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 4
DeviceID          : CPU1
Manufacturer      : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed     : 2195
Name              : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4850 v3 @ 2.20GHz
SocketDesignation : None
```

And output when I run `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -computername X | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average`:

```
0
```

This is my first post on here. As the code I'm trying to use is from Stack Overflow, I decided to post here rather than on Server Fault.

EDIT: I am looking for a way to get average cpu load from all available cpu's on the remote machines being queried and so the script will ideally work no matter how many CPU's the remote machine has.

Comment: Are you sure the loadpercentage is not actually 0? Command works fine.

Comment: It's a live SQL server with both CPU's running at 15%+ constantly as observed from Resource Monitor (perfmon /res). I've run the command at different times and value is always 0.  Command works fine on server with single CPU for me as well, but not for this server with 2 CPU's.

Comment: The Server OS and PS version could be useful information to add to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was using invoke-command instead:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName X -Credential $creds {
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | 
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average
}
```

..though I actually ended up using Get-Counter to get cpu usage (which also has the samples and intervals parameters built in):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName X -Credential $creds {
((Get-Counter -counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples).CookedValue
}
```